# How to iterate through the unread emails and save the attachments to a local folder in R?

Tags: r, sendmailr

As part of my job responsibilities, I have to open ~55 emails in each day and save the attachments to a local folder. I am tired of doing that manually in each day and looking for ways to automate this. I have found some suggestions through the web and ChatGPT such as `mailR` package. However, when I tried to run the following code, it throws an error saying that `Error in imapConnect "imapConnect" function not found`

```
# Connect to your email account
conn <- imapConnect(
  user = "name.surname@institutionname",
  password = "XXX",
  hostname = "outlook.office365.com",
  ssl = TRUE
)
```

I appreciate any answer to solve this problem or to offer alternative ways to automate reading the unread emails and saving the attachments to a local folder in R. Thank you for your attention beforehand.

Comment: Yes, ChatGPT will do that to you, in general provide an answer that a human would find plausible, regardless of what it does and if it works. This seems much more promising: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mRpostman/versions/1.0.0 It also discusses attachments.

Comment: Thank you for your follow up. The package seems to be promising but I get the following error "Login denied: the server returned an authentication error." even though I use my own personal gmail address. I searched the web a little bit but could not find something to solve this problem.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)